# Is there a workaround for retrieving data for more than 1000 messages using SendGrid Filter All Messages?

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

I have a requirement of retrieving the activity for certain category of emails sent through our SendGrid account with events occurring before specific time.

For this, I first invoke the [filter all messages](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages) endpoint of SendGrid to retrieve message IDs of the specific category of messages I am interested in bounding above using `last_event_time` parameter of the endpoint followed by retrieving activity for individual messages using the [Filter message by message ID endpoint](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-messages-by-message-id) with the retrieved message ids.

The problem that I am faced with is that the [filter all messages](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages) has a `limit` parameter with maximum value of 1000 while the number of messages for which the `last_event_time` is equal to a specific timestamp say '2021-10-10T10:10:10Z' can be more than 1000.

In this case, the use of timestamp to iteratively filter messages doesn't work as the response from [filter all messages](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages) contains data for the same set of 1000 messages. I though of using the message ID's from the data retrieved through [filter all messages](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages) to exclude data for those in subsequent calls and even tried that out but it errored out because the request uri was too long.

[image]

Not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: No, @TrieuNomad

Answer (score -2):

You can [paginate through the responses](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/how-to-use-the-sendgrid-v3-api/requests#pagination) by adding `limit` and `offset` parameters to your request URL.

For example:

```
https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/resource?limit=1000&offset=1000
```

Comment: Thanks @philnash, I think the filter all messages doesn't support offset as per the documentation. I even tried that out, but it didn't work

Comment: Can you examine the headers of the response and see if there is a `Link` header with pagination detail? Alternatively, you are bounding by the `last_event_time`, could you get a page of 1000 results and then bound the next query by the latest `last_event_time` from that set of results, excluding the 1000 you just got until you get the whole set?

Comment: No the `Link` header is not in the response. Below are the keys in the response header `['Server', 'Date', 'Content-Type', 'Transfer-Encoding', 'Connection', 'vary', 'strict-transport-security', 'x-request-id', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time', 'referrer-policy', 'x-content-type-options', 'x-ratelimit-limit', 'x-ratelimit-remaining', 'x-ratelimit-reset', 'Powered-By']`

Comment: Ok, how about the thing with the `last_event_time` then?

Comment: the `last_event_time` would work if there are not more than 1000 messages with events corresponding to a single timestamp like `2021-10-10T10:10:10Z`. In case of more than 1000 messages, using `last_event_time=2021-10-10T10:10:10Z` would get same set of messages on each call

Comment: Sounds like the best approach you can take right now is to get in touch with [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us).